# Cannot set table height and tr both

Tags: jquery, html, css

I''m using js `DataTable`, and I'm trying to set a default height for the table and a default height for the row, actually what I did is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable
    ({
        iDisplayLength: 15,
      "bLengthChange": false
    });
    $("#example").css("height", "650px");
    $("#example tbody tr").css("height", "75px !important");
} );
```

and this is my html:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For a live example I've inserted a [JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/xF8hZ/752/).

How you can see the tr does not get the default height but is too large, how can I fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by "tr does not get the default height but is too large". in this code,

Comment: @NalinAggarwal if you see I've setted 75px to tr, but is not 75px, the tr get the table height, and this is bad

Answer (score 0):

It's because, you are setting your table's height 650 px,so it's stretching down your row's to sum up to 650 px(20px for both header and footer & 305 for both data row). As table's height is working prioritize, so row's height is automatically set by table. by dividing the height between the data row's equally and for header and footer to it's default. So if you are going to set the table height, row's height is not gonna work as you are looking for it. It's better to set max height for the table and set the height for the row

```
$("#example").css("max-height", "650px");
$("#example tbody tr").css("height", "75px");
```

Comment: But I need a default datatable height.

Comment: Well!1 I don't think if it's gonna work with table height or not !! a work around for this, wrap table with div and gave the height to that div. div will take that possible space on your page. and tr will work as per the mentioned css!!